# JSP dropdowns populated from database

Tags: database, jsp, validation, model-view-controller

So actually 2 questions in here.

First off, on my page users click a button to add a new entry which directs them to a JSP form.
They fill in some information via text boxes and then there are drop downs that pull data from our database.
Some of the fields are bound by basic validation:

```
@NotNull(message="Version field may not be left blank")
```

Now I run into a problem where the user attempts to submit a new entry, with the Version field left blank.
The System correctly pops up the message informing the user they must enter a value, however then the dropdowns are now empty,
and the user must go back a page and start over to get them to load the data again.

Quite a bit of code blocks so hard to know how much or how little to post....But basically the `'add'` clicks are caught and are handled by this:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/cmsattribute_add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String Home(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {

    List<CmsGroup> list =  cmsGroupService.getCmsGroupData();
    TreeMap<Integer, String> entries = getCMSList(list);
    model.addAttribute("entries", entries);

    List<Attribute> attList = attributeService.getAttributeData();
    TreeMap<Integer, String> attResult = getAttributeList(attList);     
    model.addAttribute("attResult", attResult);

    CmsAttribute cmsAttribute = new CmsAttribute();
    model.addAttribute("cmsAttribute", cmsAttribute);
    return "/cmsattribute_insert";
}
```

and then displayed via my jsp like so:

```html
<tr>
    <td><span class="required">*</span> CMS Group ID:</td>
    <td>
        <form:select path="cmsGroupId">
            <form:options items="${entries}" /> 
        </form:select>
    </td>
    <td><form:errors path="cmsGroupId" cssClass="required" /></td>
</tr>
```

I am not sure what to do :(

**2nd question:**
Much simpler one. For a few of these tables, there is a drop-down that is populated from the server (same ways as above) but as it is an optional field `id` like to add a `'blank'` entry in the drop-down as the default when the page is loaded so that if the user does not need to add anything in that field once it is submitted nothing is passed back from it.

Any clues?

Thanks guys

Comment: Anyone have any clues? :)

Answer (score 0):

in form option maybe you can change use for each code..like this.

```
 <form:select path="cmsGroupId">
    <c:forEach var="d" items="${entries}">
       <form:options items="${d.name}" /> 
    </c:forEach>
 </form:select>
```